# How can I put Django's settings.py in source control, while still making local adjustments?

Tags: django

In a Django project, the configuration is kept in a file called `settings.py`. Deployments will generally need to make local tweaks (such as setting `LOCAL_HOSTS`).

These tweaks cannot live in the local copy of `settings.py`, because it will confuse source control.

How can we resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Keep the local settings in a file `localsettings.py` in the same directory as `settings.py`.

Do not keep an actual `localsettings.py` in source control.

At the end of `settings.py`, add:

```
try:
    from project.project.localsettings import *
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    pass
```

This includes all the symbols from `localsettings.py` in `settings.py`, and the local symbols will have priority if there are any clashes. If `localsettings.py` doesn't exist, it does nothing.

And add the local settings file to `.gitignore`:

```
/project/project/localsettings.py
```